# Replace values more than 80 percentile with 80 percentile in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as shown below
df:

```
Id     gender     age       salary
1      m          27        100
2      m          26        100000
3      m          57        180
4      f          27        150
5      m          57        200
6      f          29        100
7      m          47        130
8      f          27        140
9      m          37        100
10     f          43        2000
```

From the above I would like to replace the value more than 80 percentile value with 80 percentile value.

Expected output:

```
Id     gender     age       salary
1      m          27        100
2      m          26        560
3      m          57        180
4      f          27        150
5      m          57        200
6      f          29        100
7      m          47        130
8      f          27        140
9      m          37        100
10     f          43        560
```

Comment: Why 0.8 percentile is 200  ?

Comment: @YOBEN_S 80 percentile is not 200?

Comment: I do not think .8 is 200 ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
quantiles = df.salary.quantile(0.8)

df.loc[df.salary > quantiles, 'salary'] = quantiles
```

Output (can't quite get `200` as `.8` percentile though):

```
   Id gender  age  salary
0   1      m   27   100.0
1   2      m   26   560.0
2   3      m   57   180.0
3   4      f   27   150.0
4   5      m   57   200.0
5   6      f   29   100.0
6   7      m   47   130.0
7   8      f   27   140.0
8   9      m   37   100.0
9  10      f   43   560.0
```

In case you want to fill within `gender`:

```
quantiles = df.groupby('gender')['salary'].transform('quantile', q=0.8)
```

Output:

```
   Id gender  age  salary
0   1      m   27     100
1   2      m   26     200
2   3      m   57     180
3   4      f   27     150
4   5      m   57     200
5   6      f   29     100
6   7      m   47     130
7   8      f   27     140
8   9      m   37     100
9  10      f   43     890
```